# On the spare time / On her free time

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, ordre-des-mots

I have only studied French for a few weeks. I am writing a few sentences about my sister. Would you understand what I want to relay and does it make sense or is there some other way (better way) to formulate the sentence?

> On her free time she likes skiing, travelling and cars which are fast.
>
> Sur son temps libre, elle adore skier, voyager et conduire des voiture rapides.

Comment: I have the same problem in english than in french, "fast cars" is not a verb, whereas "ski and travel" are. I think the problem comes from you enumeration, which should be "to ski, to travel, and fast cars", otherwise, we read "to (ski + travel + fast cars)" where "to" is implied in every term...

Comment: "[Durant/Pendant/Lors de/Sur] son temps libre" is the closest translation I can think of. "À ses heures perdues" could also fit.

Comment: What about: "...faire du voyage et conduire des voiture rapides"?

Comment: I tried to explain in an answer, which is my very first here on French SE. Welcome here ! :)

Comment: @YassineBadache Welcome to FLSE ! Your answer sounds good ! Good Job ! :)

Comment: @Eva Reading Yassine's answer, I notice what seems to be an error to me in your english sentence. I've always been taught that after "like", you have to use "ing". So I think "I like to ski" should be "I like skiing". Can anyone confirm this ? :)

Comment: @Random. The English sentence is botched because I start with Swedish, use English to communicate with you to be able to learn French. thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: The most natural way to express this in English would be "*In* her free time, she likes skiing, traveling, and *fast cars*."  Or possibly "... and racing cars," if she is driving the fast cars herself, in competitions.

Comment: Yes, "I like to ski" is OK, but "\*on her free time" should definitely change to "*In* her free time..."

Comment: @psmears Indeed, it seems that "to+verb" is more common in American English refering to [this article](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/hate-like-love-and-prefer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a slight difference in your sentence between what you mean and what you write. Unfortunately, this is an important one. When you say:

> On her free time she likes to ski, travel and fast cars.

We can translate that, literraly, in:

> Pendant son temps libre elle aime skier, voyager, et les voitures rapides.

Which translate back in English to:

> On her free time she likes skiing, travelling and cars which are fast.

In French, a lot of verbs can be used without particles. For example, "faire du ski" refers as "skier", while "faire du voyager" refers as "voyager". Fast is not a *verb* in French, not as intended here (I guess), but an *adjective*, used to describe something. A fast car is a car which is fast.

In English (thanks @Aaron), fast as a verb means *"to not eat for a certain period of time"*, and refers in French as "Jeûner". (Ramadan, for example).

(I feel you, when learning english earlier I had a rough time figuring out *"a red car"*, which is *"une voiture rouge"* (a car red) in French).

If you want to say she likes driving fast cars during her free time, you could say:

> In her free time she likes skiing, travelling, and driving fast cars.

Which translates to:

> [Pendant / Durant / Lors de] son temps libre, elle adore skier, voyager, et conduire des voitures rapides.

Comment: I feel "faire du voyage" very strange, don't you ? Also, what do you mean by "I feel you" ?

Comment: "Faire du voyage" was OP's translation. And by "I feel you", I mean I'm understanding what she feels, struggling about adjectives. I thought it was an english expression, heard it a couple of times.

Comment: Ah ? I've never heard it this way, but if you do, I believe you ! :)

Comment: Note that while "fast" indeed can be a verb in English, it does not have anything to do with speed : it translates to "jeûner". Either the verb was missing from the original sentence, or it was meant to be understood as an adjective (i.e. "On her free time she likes [...] fast cars"), which is awkward too.

Comment: Oh right, forgot this one, thanks ! I'll be more precise :).

Comment: @Aaron: The verb was missing and I have added the correct verb so it is aligned with the rest.

Comment: @Yassine Badache: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @Eva to notify someone, you can't use white spaces. What you should do is start typing "@Yass", and then see the suggestions being displayed (if there is only one, you can press TAB to autocomplete) :)

Comment: +1 primarily for your good answer to the actual question but also for noting in the last English translation that "**IN** her free/spare time" (especially at the beginning of a sentence) is much more idiomatic than "**ON** her free/spare time.".... Re "I feel you," although it's certainly used just as you have used it (to express understanding sympathy/empathy), "I feel your pain" or "I hear you" are probably used more often to express that sentiment.